# Lock a main Tkinter window in Python and keep the X button running

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry if I was not specific with the question, but it is a bit long and it is my first time consulting programming issues. I was creating a *Toplevel* in *Python* with the *Tkinter* module and I wanted to block the events in the main window while it is open. Googled and I found the method "*grab_set*", which takes me to the other end. That is, it blocks the events in the top bar of the window (close, maximize and minimize). Is there something similar to *grab_set* but without this happening?

As an alternative, I can block all the entrys and buttons, but I don't know any way to unlink or re-link the binds. Is there any way?

```
original = Tk()
entrada = Entry(original)
entrada.pack()

def otra_ventana(Self):
    ventana = Toplevel(original)
    ventana.grab_set()

original.bind("<F1>", otra_ventana)
```

The above is a test code that has the problem that I mentioned.

*Postscript:* The problem only occurs when the Toplevel is open and an attempt is made to close the main window.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Dante, Welcome to SO. Please take some time to look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it will help you writing a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dorian Turba

Comment: stovfl Thanks the same for the link, but, as I mentioned earlier, grab_set blocks the events in the top bar of the main window. That is, I press the close button in the main window and it does not close. Try with protocol and it didn't work.

Comment: If you meant wait_window, it doesn't work for me either. This is because this pause the code, but, for example, I can still write in the entrys and use the binds in the main window. Thanks the same again.

Comment: @DanteS. ***"keep the X button running"***: Now I have **two** `X`, and both working for me? Did you claim you can't close any of the windwo by clicking `X`?

Comment: It just does not close the main window. Try closing the main window first. I did not clarify that the main window can be closed when you close the toplevel. I will add it in the question to make it even clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ready, I'm done. Thanks to all for the help. For those who have this problem I leave the solution that occurred to me based on my conclusions and the Mike - SMT code.

```
from tkinter import *

original = Tk()
original.active = True # enter this variable in class Tk
entrada = Entry(original)
entrada.pack()

def toogle(Self=None):
    original.active = not original.active

    for widget in original.winfo_children():
        # only change the state if "state" exists in config and the widget is not Label
        if(widget.config().get("state") and widget.winfo_class() != "Label"):
            widget["state"] = {True:"normal", False:"disabled"}[original.active]

def otra_ventana(Self):
    if(original.active):
        ventana = Toplevel(original)
        ventana.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda:(toogle(), ventana.destroy()))
        toogle()

original.bind("<F1>", otra_ventana)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you do not like what grab_set is doing then you could simply disable all widgets in the root window and re-enable them after the top level is closed.

Using `winfo_children()` we can set up a function to toggle the state of widgets in the root window.

Combined with `protocol()` we can decide what happens when the toplevel window is closed.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk


def toggle_root_state(state='normal'):
    for child in original.winfo_children():
        try:
            child['state'] = state
        except:
            pass


def otra_ventana(_=None):
    ventana = tk.Toplevel(original)
    ventana.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: (toggle_root_state(), ventana.destroy()))
    toggle_root_state('disabled')


original = tk.Tk()
original.geometry('225x50')
entrada = tk.Entry(original)
entrada.pack()
original.bind("<F1>", otra_ventana)
original.mainloop()
```

Comment: I thought the same as you, but not so well coded. Unfortunately, that method does not deactivate binds. I would say "use unbind and then create them again", but I create binds in a personal module, which does not make it so simple.That is why, in the question, I mentioned that as an alternative a method was used to deactivate and reactivate binds. Thanks the same for the dedication.

Comment: the same is a possible solution

Comment: I was analyzing my module and I think I can play with the conditionals and what you proposed to achieve what I want to achieve. I am going to try and let you know as soon as I have it ready.

Comment: If you also want to deactivate the bind you can do so in the function.

Comment: @DanteS. I have added the functionality to add or remove binding.